# Android Studio 0.4.4 - Not showing root level directories

Tags: android, android-studio, directory-structure

**EDIT:**

Looks to be a bug. Report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65709

---

I have an Android project with the following structure:

[image: finder window]

Since updating to Android Studio 0.4.4 when I import at the project_root level, I'm automatically dropped down to the "ProjectSearch" level in the Project view. Other root level files shows up in the Project view (in a strange highlighted list) but no directories (`notes`, `keystore`, etc)

Why is this? Should I be organizing my project differently? I didn't change any configuration that I'm aware of... just updated to 0.4.4.

**Edit** (screenshots):

Project View

[image: project view]

Modules

[image: Modules]

settings.gradle

```
include ':ProjectSearch' // (main project name)
```

Comment: The directories still exists on your hard drive?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your project viewer and also the Modules panel of the Project Structure dialog? This could be a bug but I'd like to have a look at it.

Comment: @martijnn2008 yes, the directories still exist.

Comment: @ScottBarta working on that now.

Comment: @ScottBarta updated with screenshots.

Comment: Okay, I'm close to seeing the issue. Can you add the contents of your settings.gradle file?

Comment: @ScottBarta not much there. Just the main project. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your **settings.gradle** file is in the wrong directory -- it should be in your project's root directory, not in the **MainProject** directory. It looks like you have Gradle wrapper and other files in your module, too -- those only need to be at the root.

It also looks like you have a **build.gradle** file in the wrong place -- there's one in **MainProject/src** -- it should be in **MainProject**.

**EDIT**

Your directory structure looks okay for a project where **project_root** is the root, and I see by your original description that Android Studio has suddenly decided that **ProjectSearch** is now the root when it goes to display it. Your **settings.gradle** file seems okay, and based on your directory listing, the **build.gradle** files are in the right place, and Android Studio is just displaying things wrong.

I'd try just re-importing the project in Android Studio. To do that:

1. Close your project
2. Back up your project
3. Delete the **.idea** folder in the project root and all the **.iml** files.
4. Import the project again and choose the **build.gradle** file in the root directory.

Comment: Hm... I think my blurred paths caused confusion. My root folder is `ProjectSearch`. Within this folder is `SearchApp` where the primary application lives. I have settings.gradle, gradlew stuff, and project -wide build.gradle file in the root `ProjectSearch`. There's a separate build.gradle file in the `SearchApp` directory (NOT in `ProjectSearch/src`... the image makes it look that way). I'll edit my question with a regular finder window screenshot with folder structure.

Comment: Updated with a finder screenshot of the project... also updated the question to reference specific file names. Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to use vague references instead of specific names which just made things worse.

Comment: Okay, I re-read your original question and understand it better now. I edited my answer; give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: I removed the .idea folder and .iml files, and I get the same issue when selecting the root level build.gradle file (it acts the same as selecting the root folder). Is there some view setting I may have accidentally toggled? What's the recommended project structure... I thought I was doing what was recommended. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Your project structure looks okay. I think at this point it's a bug in Android Studio, and there's nothing Stack Overflow can gain by us trying to puzzle it out in the comments. Could you please file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug and attach your idea.log file (Help menu > Show log). That log file could be very useful. Thanks for everything you've tried, and sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: I filed a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65709. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottBarta, are multiple settings.gradle files, i.e. a settings.gradle file in a java library that the android application depends on?

Comment: You can't have multiple settings.gradle files; it only looks at one.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I started seeing this issue again when creating a new project in Android Studio 0.8.9... Removing as a marked answer but keeping it around for the sake of history.

This seems to be a bug in Android Studio 0.4.4. See the conversation with Scott Barta (Google Employee). The bug report can be seen at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65709

---

<s>**Edit:** This was resolved for me sometime between 0.5.6 and 0.5.7.</s>